# spearman correlation by group in R

Tags: r

How do you calculate Spearman correlation by group in R.  I found the following link talking about Pearson correlation by group.  But when I tried to replace the type with spearman, it does not work.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about this for a base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("G1", "G2"), each = 10),
                 var1 = rnorm(20),
                 var2 = rnorm(20))

r <- by(df, df$group, FUN = function(X) cor(X$var1, X$var2, method = "spearman"))
# df$group: G1
# [1] 0.4060606
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# df$group: G2
# [1] 0.1272727
```

And then, if you want the results in the form of a data.frame:

```
data.frame(group = dimnames(r)[[1]], corr = as.vector(r))
#   group      corr
# 1    G1 0.4060606
# 2    G2 0.1272727
```

**EDIT**: If you prefer a `plyr`-based solution, here is one:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(group), summarise, "corr" = cor(var1, var2, method = "spearman"))
```

Comment: (+1) Nice answer. What about `r <- by(df, df$group, FUN = function(X) cor(df[,-1], method = "spearman"))`?

Comment: @MYaseen208. Thanks. The code you give returns something slightly different. I don't know its name, but its like a variance-covariance matrix, except with a correlation in each cell. The code I used returns, instead, a single scalar correlation for each group.

Comment: @Myaseen208 I toyed around with something like that too but as Josh mentions it doesn't produce the same output.  When you throw a matrix/dataframe into cor it spits back out a matrix.  If you comma separate your vectors it just spits out the correlation between those two.

Comment: Great post Josh, plyr is a valuable tool.

Answer (score 11):

very old question, but this `tidy` & `broom` solution is extremely straightforward. Thus I have to share the approach:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("G1", "G2"), each = 10),
                 var1 = rnorm(20),
                 var2 = rnorm(20))

library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df  %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(correlation = cor(var1, var2,, method = "sp"))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  group correlation
  <fct>       <dbl>
1 G1        -0.200 
2 G2         0.0545

# with pvalues and further stats
df %>% 
  nest(-group) %>% 
  mutate(cor=map(data,~cor.test(.x$var1, .x$var2, method = "sp"))) %>%
  mutate(tidied = map(cor, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidied, .drop = T)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  group estimate statistic p.value method                          alternative
  <fct>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                           <chr>      
1 G1     -0.200        198   0.584 Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
2 G2      0.0545       156   0.892 Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided
```

Since some time/`dplyr` version, you need to write this to get results like above and no errors:

```
df %>% 
  nest(data = -group) %>%
  mutate(cor=map(data,~cor.test(.x$var1, .x$var2, method = "sp"))) %>%
  mutate(tidied = map(cor, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidied) %>% 
  select(-data, -cor)
```

Comment: What does "each=10" mean?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way to do it:

```
# split the data by group then apply spearman correlation
# to each element of that list
j <- lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x){cor(x[,2], x[,3], method = "spearman")})

# Bring it together
data.frame(group = names(j), corr = unlist(j), row.names = NULL)
```

Comparing my method, Josh's method, and the plyr solution using rbenchmark:

```
Dason <- function(){
    # split the data by group then apply spearman correlation
    # to each element of that list
    j <- lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x){cor(x[,2], x[,3], method = "spearman")})

    # Bring it together
    data.frame(group = names(j), corr = unlist(j), row.names = NULL)
}

Josh <- function(){
    r <- by(df, df$group, FUN = function(X) cor(X$var1, X$var2, method = "spearman"))
    data.frame(group = attributes(r)$dimnames[[1]], corr = as.vector(r))
}

plyr <- function(){
    ddply(df, .(group), summarise, "corr" = cor(var1, var2, method = "spearman"))
}


library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(Dason(), Josh(), plyr())
```

Which gives the output

```
> benchmark(Dason(), Josh(), plyr())
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 Dason()          100    0.19 1.000000      0.19        0         NA        NA
2  Josh()          100    0.24 1.263158      0.22        0         NA        NA
3  plyr()          100    0.51 2.684211      0.52        0         NA        NA
```

So it appears my method is slightly faster but not by much.  I think Josh's method is a little more intuitive.  The plyr solution is the easiest to code up but it's not the fastest (but it sure is a lot more convenient)!

Comment: Thanks for thinking to test those out with `benchmark`. +1 for putting that together. I have a couple of additional comments. (1) On repeated calls to benchmark, the usual difference between the `lapply(split(...)` and `by(...)` approaches is more like 7-10%. (2) If you're interested in pursuing this further, it'd probably be more useful to test the three methods on some large data.frames, with 1000+ groups and 1e6+ rows. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Dason too for your time!!

Answer (score 5):

If you want an efficient solution for large numbers of groups then `data.table` is the way to go.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(DT, group)
DT[,list(corr = cor(var1,var2,method = 'spearman')), by = group]
```

Comment: +1 Note the `setkey` is optional. Keyed-by is only faster than unkeyed-by for very large datasets (e.g. 1e7 rows+) where there are a lot of large groups as well. Unkeyed-by is already pretty fast.