# How can I find the correlation coefficient between two columns by factors?

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe. I want to calculate the correlation coefficient between **hot** and **index**, by class

```
ID    hot   index class
41400 10      2   a
41400 12      2   a
41400 75      4   a
41401 89      5   a 
41401 25      3   c
41401 100     6   c
20445 67      4   c
20445 89      6   c
20445 4       1   c
20443 67      5   d
20443 120.2   7   a
20443 140.5   8   d
20423 170.5   10   d
20423 78.1    5   c
```

Intended output

```
a = 0.X (assumed numbers)
b = 0.Y
c = 0.Z
```

I know I can use the **by** command, but I am not able to.

Code

```
cor_eqn = function(df){
  m = cor(hot ~ index, df);

}

by(df,df$class,cor_eqn,simplify = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
gp = group_by(dataset, class)
correl = dplyr::summarise(gp, correl = cor(hot, index))
print(correl)

#  class   correl
#   a      0.9815492
#   c      0.9753372
#   d      0.9924337
```

Note that `class` and `df` are R functions, names like these can cause trouble.

Comment: package ‘dplyr’ is not available  (for R version 3.0.1)? Not sure what happened

Comment: Maybe you need to install it: `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: It says it is not available for  R version 3.0.1)

Comment: Maybe it's time to upgrade your R version, but there are other ways of solving this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791650/spearman-correlation-by-group-in-r

Comment: thank you. I got it. However, dplyr doesn't get installed even after upgrading. All other libraries are working fine.

Comment: @maximusyoda so I have to ask (and Fernando no disrespect is meant here - perfectly good answer to me) *why did you accept the answer if it is not working for you?!*.

Comment: Umm....The answer he linked to in the comment worked for me. Not sure what to do in that case. Hence I accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a `data.table` instead of a `data.frame`. You can just call `setDT(df)` on your existing `data.frame` (I created a `data.table` initially below):

```
library(data.table)
##
set.seed(123)
DT <- data.table(
  ID=1:50000,
  class=rep(
    letters[1:4],
    each=12500),
  hot=rnorm(50000),
  index=rgamma(50000,shape=2))
## set key for better performance 
## with large data set
setkeyv(DT,class)
##
> DT[,list(Correlation=cor(hot,index)),by=class]
   class  Correlation
1:     a  0.005658200
2:     b  0.001651747
3:     c -0.002147164
4:     d -0.006248392
```