# Conditional calculation of correlations

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, apply, correlation

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Year Class Value1  Value2  Value3
2006    A    45      27      96
2007    A    74      45      26
2008    C    74      41      78 
2009    D    56      65      45
2010    C    12      14      15
2011    A    25      85      50 
2012    B    26      45      12
2013    C    15      23      29
2014    D    86      36      53
```

How can I find correlations between Value1 and Value2; Value1 and Value3 for all rows?

I`am trying to do that for Value1 and Value2:

```
cor <- data[,list(correlation=cor(Value1,Value2)),by=list(Year, Class)]
```

But get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , list(correlation = cor(Value1, Value2)),  : 
  unused argument (by = list(Year, Class))
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791650/spearman-correlation-by-group-in-r and this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group

Comment: Is that your entire table, or is there more than one row for each combination of `Year` and `Class` in your actual data frame?

Comment: @eipi This is entire table

Comment: @RichardScriven I mean calculate correlations for each Year - 4 rows.

Comment: so you want `cor(25, 85)` then `cor(25, 50)`, and so on?  It really doesn't make much sense to do that

Comment: You can't calculate the correlation between two individual numbers. It's undefined.

Comment: @eipi10 I edited the table. I need to calculate correlations between Value1&Value2 and Value1&Value2  for each type of Class.

Comment: @RichardScriven  I edited the table. I need to calculate correlations between Value1&Value2 and Value1&Value2  for each type of Class.

Comment: @Mike.Gahan Could you please help me with approach using data.table?

Comment: You need to load the `data.table` package so that you won't get that error (i.e. `library(data.table)`), but after doing that, you're still probably not going to be happy with the results.

Comment: @GSee I loaded the package data.table but I get the error:   'x' must be numeric. I did "as.numeric()" but still get that error.

Comment: Please make this [reproducible](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000).  Edit your Question to include the output of `dput(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to return a list in which each list element is the correlation matrix for a given value of `Class`. Assume the table in your question is a data frame called `dat`:

Adapted from [this CrossValidated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/r-compute-correlation-by-group):

```
library(plyr)

corrFunc <- function(dat) {
  return(data.frame(cor(dat[,-c(1,2)])))
}

corr.list = dlply(dat, .(Class), corrFunc)
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```
$A
           Value1     Value2     Value3
Value1  1.0000000 -0.5920024 -0.4347386
Value2 -0.5920024  1.0000000 -0.4684250
Value3 -0.4347386 -0.4684250  1.0000000

$B
       Value1 Value2 Value3
Value1     NA     NA     NA
Value2     NA     NA     NA
Value3     NA     NA     NA

$C
          Value1    Value2    Value3
Value1 1.0000000 0.9580847 0.9855342
Value2 0.9580847 1.0000000 0.9927778
Value3 0.9855342 0.9927778 1.0000000

$D
       Value1 Value2 Value3
Value1      1     -1      1
Value2     -1      1     -1
Value3      1     -1      1

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
  Class
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
```

Comment: Thank you! Can add result in the table: 1st column "A,B,C,D", second column Correlations between Value1&Value2, third column Correlations between Value1&Value3