# Using ddply to find correlation of a dataframe for separate groups for R

Tags: r, plyr

```
ds <- structure(list(GPA = c(1.78, 2.38, 2.43, 1.98, 1.56, 2.32, 1.96, 
2.73, 2, 3.59), STUDY_STAGE = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), OLAGG = c(18, 14, 14, 17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 14, 15)), .Names = c("GPA", 
"STUDY_STAGE", "OLAGG"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've made reference to this post
[spearman correlation by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791650/spearman-correlation-by-group-in-r)

However, when I attempted to find the correlation based on sub group STUDY_STAGE (there are 3), I obtained all same values.

```
ddply(ds,.(STUDY_STAGE), summarise, cor(ds$GPA, ds$OLAGG, method = "spearman")) 
STUDY_STAGE        ..1
1           1 -0.2805924
2           2 -0.2805924
3           3 -0.2805924
```

Additional information on the dataframe

```
str(ds)
'data.frame':   3167 obs. of  3 variables:
$ GPA        : num  1.78 2.38 2.43 1.98 1.56 2.32 1.96 2.73 2 3.59 ...
$ STUDY_STAGE: int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ OLAGG      : num  18 14 14 17 17 16 16 15 14 15 ...
```

Just to show that they should have different correlation values:

```
ds.yr1<-ds[ds$STUDY_STAGE=="Yr 1",]
cor(ds.yr1$GPA, ds.yr1$OLAGG)
[1] -0.3313926

ds.yr2<-ds[ds$STUDY_STAGE=="Yr 2",]
cor(ds.yr2$GPA, ds.yr2$OLAGG)
[1] -0.2905399
```

Full data is available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64487083/R/mydata.csv

Question:
How can I find the correlation for all the 3 different study_stage?

Thank you all for your time and effort!

Comment: The answer is already in the link provided.  It seems to me that while you were changing the names of the variable, added the `ds$` which created the problem.

Comment: @akrun Thanks very much! You have been helping tremendously in my learning journey on R; answering most of my posts *8 ). Frankly, I could never figure out these nuances in R. Pls post your answer again, it is useful to help newbies on R like me.

Comment: Also, it seems most of the solutions were covered in those links, but you may want to try `data.table` too (would be the most efficient one), something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(ds)[, list(Cor = cor(GPA, OLAGG, method = "spearman")), by = STUDY_STAGE]` should work

Comment: @Raphael Lee No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `ds$GPA` and `ds$OLAGG`, we are calculating the `cor` of the whole columns instead of by groups.

```
 ds <- read.csv("mydata.csv") #full data from the link

 cor(ds$GPA, ds$OLAGG, method='spearman')
 #[1] -0.2805924


ddply(ds,.(STUDY_STAGE), summarise, Cor=cor(GPA, OLAGG, method = "spearman"))
#    STUDY_STAGE        Cor
#1        Yr 1 -0.3337192
#2        Yr 2 -0.2803793
#3        Yr 3 -0.2090219

cor(ds.yr1$GPA, ds.yr1$OLAGG, method='spearman')
#[1] -0.3337192
```