# group_by dplyr is not grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

Ok, so I've read lots of posts here and I'm kind of embarrassed because I thought I understood the basic `dplyr`functions.

I can't get `group_by` to form groups and I am perplexed.

I have the data frame `test`. All I want is to group by the variable `ID` and then calculate the correlation between two variables per group.

I don't know what's happening because it doesn't group and only outputs 1 correlation when I should have 127 groups and 127 correlations. WHY?

What `test` looks like:

[image]

What I wrote:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
test%>%
  mutate(ID=as.character(ID))%>%
  group_by(ID)%$%
  cor(sulfate,nitrate,use="complete.obs")
```

What I get: `[1] 0.0568084`.

Comment: 1. Please `dput` your test data. 2. `library(magrittr)` is unnecessary.

Comment: How many ID's there are? Maybe it's only one

Comment: @Emil, OK, I will `dput` my test data. I thought `library(magrittr)` is necessary for the `%$%`operator.

Comment: The pipe operator comes preloaded in `dplyr`. Also, your `mutate` is unnecessary. Just do `test %>% group_by(ID)...`

Comment: I guess you need the relatively obscure dplyr verb `do` (if I understand your desired output correctly). You are correct that magrittr is necessary for `%$%`.

Comment: @Emil, I beg to differ. I am using the pipe `%>%` operator but also the exposition `%$%` operator which is not preloaded in `dplyr`.

Comment: base R solution to double check: `by(test, test$ID, function(X) cor(X$sulfate, X$nitrate, use = "p"))` Maybe can even be duplicate to (but not `dplyr` solution): [spearman correlation by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791650/spearman-correlation-by-group-in-r)

Comment: @PoGibas, your base R solution works great. Would like to learn the `dplyr` way though.

Comment: @Frank, I will check out this obscure `do` verb. Thanks.

Comment: @delcast, that was an error on my part... I've never encountered `%$%` operator. Thanks for your question as we were all treated to a really nice answer from CalumYou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think the exposition pipe `%$%` will freely provide `dplyr` semantics with `group_by`. I haven't looked at the source but just thinking about it, what would expect your code to return? A vector with 127 correlation values? You wouldn't even be able to know which one came from which ID. I suggest that you stick to wrapping operations inside `mutate` and `summarise` when possible, which I think is the intended usage. Note that this provides the same advantage of `%$%` which is avoiding having to specify the data frame context (i.e. can just write `mpg` instead of `mtcars$mpg`). I wouldn't use `do` here, since there is no need (your output is going to be vector and not anything more exotic like a model).

Example using the built in `mtcars` dataset below.

If you need the vector of correlations, it's easy to extract after this operation.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(cor = cor(mpg, hp))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>    gear    cor
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     3 -0.739
#> 2     4 -0.879
#> 3     5 -0.900
```

Created on 2018-07-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Yup! This worked great. I guess it was trying to use the exposition pipe with 'group_by`. I did get my 127 correlations. Thanks!

Comment: Great explanation!